# intent is not returning data

Tags: android, bundle

I am developing an Android project in which I have to send data from one activity to another. But when I'm sending data from one activity to another it is not sending data from one activity to another.

Part of code receiving data from other is:

```
Intent intent=getIntent();
String str,str1;
str=intent.getExtras().getString("phoneno"); 
Log.d("completre", "complete"); 
phonePhoneno.setText(str);

Log.d("complete","complete1");



if(intent.getExtras()==null) {
    txtMessage.setText("u duffer write program properly");
} else {
    str1=intent.getExtras().toString();
    txtMessage.setText(str1);
    Log.d("complete","complete2");
}
```

Part of code I'm using for sending data from other activity is:

```
if(v.getId()==R.id.main_act) {
    String str=txtText.getText().toString();
    Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("username",str);
    intent.putExtra("phoneno", phoneno);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

When I try to receive data by clicking button it is force closing.

in this project i have two activity in first activity i m reading a telephone no. ans sending it to second activity only to save it for future. in the second activity i have an edit text in which i am adding text by voice recognition system after that i am sending both data telephone no and edit text field from 2nd activity to 1st activity by clcking button just shown above (in second part of code) . it is sending phone no but not edit text content(guess) , when i click complete button(to fill both field in 1st activity) then it adds phone no in phone no field but does not add message.

latest  log cat
 when app didn't close itself

```
  04-13 13:33:46.206: I/TextToSpeech(834): Sucessfully bound to com.svox.pico
04-13 13:33:46.206: W/TextToSpeech(834): speak failed: not bound to TTS engine
04-13 13:33:47.005: I/TextToSpeech(834): Connected to ComponentInfo{com.svox.pico/com.svox.pico.PicoService}
04-13 13:33:47.125: E/test(834): hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh
04-13 13:33:47.125: I/Choreographer(834): Skipped 174 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-13 13:33:47.575: I/Choreographer(834): Skipped 69 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-13 13:33:56.535: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(834): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
04-13 13:33:56.535: I/Choreographer(834): Skipped 174 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-13 13:33:56.975: D/dalvikvm(834): GC_CONCURRENT freed 127K, 9% free 3017K/3288K, paused 37ms+5ms, total 108ms
04-13 13:34:00.274: V/(834): Got a contact result: content://com.android.contacts/data/3
04-13 13:34:00.674: V/(834): Got phone no : (986) 743-561
04-13 13:34:00.914: I/Choreographer(834): Skipped 164 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-13 13:34:01.244: I/Choreographer(834): Skipped 37 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-13 13:34:05.494: I/Choreographer(834): Skipped 139 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-13 13:34:05.974: I/Choreographer(834): Skipped 60 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-13 13:34:12.965: I/TextToSpeech(834): Sucessfully bound to com.svox.pico
04-13 13:34:12.965: W/TextToSpeech(834): speak failed: not bound to TTS engine
04-13 13:34:13.065: I/TextToSpeech(834): Connected to ComponentInfo{com.svox.pico/com.svox.pico.PicoService}
04-13 13:34:13.155: E/test(834): hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh
04-13 13:34:13.155: I/Choreographer(834): Skipped 35 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-13 13:34:14.425: I/Choreographer(834): Skipped 308 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-13 13:34:15.235: I/Choreographer(834): Skipped 95 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-13 13:34:16.265: I/Choreographer(834): Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
 04-13 13:34:20.025: D/completre(834): complete
 04-13 13:34:20.035: D/AndroidRuntime(834): Shutting down VM
 04-13 13:34:20.035: W/dalvikvm(834): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
 04-13 13:34:20.085: E/AndroidRuntime(834): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 04-13 13:34:20.085: E/AndroidRuntime(834): java.lang.NullPointerException
 04-13 13:34:20.085: E/AndroidRuntime(834):     at com.example.sms.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:322)
 04-13 13:34:20.085: E/AndroidRuntime(834):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
 04-13 13:34:20.085: E/AndroidRuntime(834):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
 04-13 13:34:20.085: E/AndroidRuntime(834):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
 04-13 13:34:20.085: E/AndroidRuntime(834):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
 04-13 13:34:20.085: E/AndroidRuntime(834):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
 04-13 13:34:20.085: E/AndroidRuntime(834):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
 04-13 13:34:20.085: E/AndroidRuntime(834):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 04-13 13:34:20.085: E/AndroidRuntime(834):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
 04-13 13:34:20.085: E/AndroidRuntime(834):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
 04-13 13:34:20.085: E/AndroidRuntime(834):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
 04-13 13:34:20.085: E/AndroidRuntime(834):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

i more thing that i would like to mention here is that when i return from second activity to main without recording any message that i didn't set content of edit text and i tried to send the content to first activity as shown in second part of code it worked ...ideally it should force close itself since edit text had no data ..i could not understand why it is not force closing itself at that time.

Comment: Add the stacktrace, so we can see which exception it's throwing - also if you could point out the line, that crashes the app.

Comment: should i update the question i.e i should add more code part to make it clear??

Comment: Considering that your `Activity` is called "MainActivity" and your button id is "main_act", this looks suspect. "main_act.xml" may be the filename of your XML layout file, and this would be a mistake. See my answer edit below.

Comment: no main.act is my button id i m sure about that.

Comment: And what line is line `322` in your `MainActivity`?

Comment: @Darwind it is line in which i m setting content of phone no field. phonephoneno.settext(str). this line is there in 1st part of code it is commented out as i thought it is working f9.

Comment: Uhm, then the stacktrace isn't really worth anything, because this is the line, that is crashing your app with a `NullPointerException` - clean-build the app and re-install it on your device of choice. After that, post the new stacktrace.

Comment: logcat updated still force close...please help

Comment: anyone please help me :(   ...m waiting

Comment: Ok, so it's crashing the same place - at line 322 in `MainActivity`. That doesn't make sense, if this is still the outcommented code. Can't help you much then. Maybe paste all your code to pastebin.org or upload the full project as a zip file to DropBox and share the link - anything, so we can examine the problem in full.

Comment: just want to know one thing if u don't pass anything in edit text and try to send its content using intent to other activity how should it perform that is it should force close it self or not???

Comment: pasted at pastebin.org my username is rajeevnitj post name is android_voice_sms

Comment: should i make this question more clear and detail  please response hoping for some solution

Comment: question updated ... @Darwind  u were right after a long research i came to the same point it is line no 322 which is causing crash...but i could not find any solution ...it is still returning null pointer exception

Comment: @sid ok I've added an answer to your question - hope you understand and like it ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after a bit of digging, I found out what the problem was...

The problem doesn't have anything to do with the values from the `Bundle`.

The problem is that you're trying to call `setText()` and `getText()` on an `EditText` called `phonePhoneno`. This field has never been initialized in the `onCreate` method of the `MainActivity`.

So, to fix this `NullPointerException`, initialize the `phonePhoneno` to the correct `EditText` inside your `main.xml` for `MainActivity` and you're good ;-)

Maybe it should initialized like this?

```
phonePhoneno = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.phonenofromcontact);
```

I don't know?

It looks like a type or an "autocomplete" mistake to be honest :P

Just a little advice: Clean up your code, and you'd probably have found the `Exception` on your own ;-)

Comment: and yeah u r right problem could be easily found but....u know while checking code v generally skip easy part :P sometimes v have to pay for that (it cost me 1 day in this case ;) :)

Answer (score 1):

**Bundle Usage**:

Use this to get the variables from your `Intent`:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
if(bundle != null) {
    String username = bundle.getString("username");
    String phoneno = bundle.getString("phoneno");
}
```

**Force Close**:

- Make sure that the variables `str` and `phoneno` are not `null` for
  your `intent.putExtra()` commands. This could cause your force close.
- Make sure that `id` "main_act" is the ***unique*** id defined in the
  XML layout file for your button.

Comment: Actually that's not entirely true - the `Bundle` has a `toString()` so it would return a human readable string, or as the documentation states: `Returns a string containing a concise, human-readable description of this object.` - also he checked for `null` - just saying ;-)

Comment: Hehe - sorry didn't see you changed the answer ;-)

Answer (score 0):

David Manperl right to say that you did something wrong you mean where are changed at Intent.
If you have an intent does not help, you can use another way. There are other ways to pass data another activity.

For example:

1. [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)
2. The Application object is another way though, and it is sometimes easier when dealing with the same state across multiple activities (as opposed to having to get/put it everywhere), or objects more complex than primitives and Strings.
   You can extend Application, and then set/get whatever you want there and access it from any Activity (in the same application) with getApplication().

Or try to get data from the Intent in onCreate method of Activity